# Regex extract string before integer

Tags: regex

I have a pack of number say :

- d123sd
- dds123
- 123ss
- dd542334ssdf
- fsd54345ff

the full data always string int string, I use this to split it each group

```
string1 = ^(.*?)\D+
int2 = (\d+)
string3 = ([a - zA - Z] *$)
```

but I always gets an error if data only int string (example 123ss), since it's variable string1 reads the first digit, can anybody tell me where did I go wrong?

Comment: Use a single regex with 3 capture groups: `^([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)$`

Comment: Maybe `string1 = ^(\D*)`? To match 0 or more non-digit chars at the start of a string. Or the whole string pattern: `^(\D*)(\d+)(\D*)$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes exactly hows that do? you can answer it so I can accept is as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To match 0 or more non-digit chars at the start of a string you need to define your `string1` as

```
string1 = ^(\D*)
```

It will capture 0 or more non-digit (`\D`) chars at the start of the string (`^`).

The whole string pattern can look like

```
^(\D*)(\d+)(\D*)$
```

See the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%5CD*)(%5Cd%2B)(%5CD*)%24):

[image]

See also the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xrfdqZ/1).